# Free Remixing Software

Tags: audio, music-production

I'm interested in getting my feet wet in music remixing. I am a complete newbie, and don't really know the exact features I'm looking for.

Requirements:

- Free. I would however consider paying a small amount for the perfect solution.
- Runs natively on Mac or Linux.
- Relatively easy to use.
- Should support a variety of file formats for import/export.

I have looked into [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), but it seems to be more focused on simple edits to pre-recorded tracks. I also tried [GarageBand](http://www.apple.com/mac/garageband/), but it seems to be focused on recording my own music. If either of these programs are my best option, please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Mixxx](http://www.mixxx.org/):

- Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux
- free and open source (GPL v2)
- It's basically a mixing software, so you can use it to record remixes on the fly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[VirtualDJ](http://www.filehorse.com/download-virtual-dj/) is a very good software, which I think will support your needs. But the problem is that it has only Windows version. So to run it in Linux you should first install Wine and then install VirtualDJ using Wine. Hope this will help you.